# Visual Studio 2008 Deployment Project Issues?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-deployment

I have created a successful deployment project using Windows Fourms that work as intended but there are two things that need to be solved:-

First: I have to click the setup.exe file in order for the installation to check for the perquisites, and if click the setup.msi it proceeds to install the software directly without checking anything.

Second: When i click on the setup file while the software is already installed on my PC, i get an error message "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel" while i should get a Repair and Remove options.

Can anybody help me solve this problems ?

Comment: Regarding first question. That's how it work: Setup.exe is the bootstrapper, and the .msi contains your install package.

Answer (score 0):

1. As said by Morten, that's how it works. You want to make sure that the prerequisites are (get) installed before your product is installed.
2. This probably is caused by a rebuild of the deployment package after you installed it. Windows installer notices that you use a different MSI (with a different package code), that  contains the same product version. This situation, apparently, is inconclusive enough to leave it up to you what to do with it. The logic of this, I think, is to prevent a "Repair" that in fact installs a different product. Inconvenient for testing, but very much desirable in production environments. If you try to install the *same* MSI you should get the repair/remove options.

BTW, after building a release, you can right-click the setup project in VS and choose "install". This executes a setup that kindly removes a previous installation with the same version.